# Making an on-the-fly 'ajaxForm'

Tags: jquery, ajaxform, on-the-fly

I am trying to use `ajaxForm` on my on-the-fly created form. In fact, my application will produce a link 'on the fly' and by clicking on that link, it will produce an `ajaxForm` (again on-the-fly by jQuery!), so I used the `.live()` function with `ajaxForm()`. This is my **wrong** code:

```
$('form').live('submit', function() {
    $(this).ajaxForm({dataType: 'html', success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }});
    return false; // For preventing page refresh!
});
```

In my form, when I click the submit button, the page refreshes.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Do you need an on the fly solution on the fly?

Comment: You haven't shown us enough. We have no idea where you execute this code, or how you include jQuery, nor can we see the problem in action.

Comment: yes, data will receive from server after loading page. and the form will be shown after clicking on a link, that link is part of process method of received data

Comment: That is not useful information. :)

Comment: :) sorry, my mind is full of errors! how you include jQuery: simple script tag (produced by cakephp). the jQuery.js works on other elements, so it is included correctly. can we see the problem in action: it is not possible for me

Comment: Why on earth not? If you can't produce a testcase then something is _very_ wrong!

Comment: oh in my test script it worked! http://pastebin.com/XC6WTch7

Comment: Right, so you have just proved that this is a complete non-question. Next time please try that _before_ posting.

Comment: see title of question, _problem_ in making ..., and that problem isn't fixed up to now. 'Please avoid extended discussions in comments'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, your `return false` should work.

So, something else is wrong. Ensure that jQuery is loaded properly and that your on-submit handler *actually executes* by placing debugging code in it.

Also, make sure that you have Firebug installed and enabled (or equivalent for your browser) so that you can perform your debugging.

Comment: with all these answeres problem should be this! ok i will test it now

Answer (score 0):

Try using event.stopPropagation(); which is a JQuery function.

To do so you will need to take the event object as parameter to the handeler:

```
$('form').live('submit', function(event){
```

and use this line in place of `return false;` :

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Try adding `url:"#"` to the object passed to the ajaxForm function.

Comment: Drew you have it  backwards, you don't want to stop propagation, you just want to prevent the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The `return false` should work, but, it's best practice to either do `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()` when you have no need to do both. In this case it would be `event.preventDefault()` because you want to stop the default action of submitting the form. But like i said `return false;` should have worked in your case so i'm suspecting you might be getting some kind of errors with the plugin you're using. If i were you i would look at the documentation again for [your](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm)
plugin and make sure your options are correct. Right off the back i see a `dataType: 'html'` and there can only be `'xml', 'script', or 'json'` as stated in the documentation...You may want to have another look at your usage of the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to call `preventDefault` in place of "return false". Pseudo code of that use case of `jQuery live`with form combined with AJAX is below:

```
    //Override form submit
    $("form").live("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'), // Get the action URL to send AJAX to
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(), // get all form variables
            success: function(result){
                // ... do your AJAX post result
            }
        });
    });
```

Also, I am not sure if with ajaxForm (as I haven't used ajaxForm) you need to use `jQuery.live`. Inferring from the doc, you might not need it at all.